# ft_one_hot_endcoder or ft_one_hot_encoder_estimator when using sparklyr's xgboost function?

Tags: r, apache-spark, xgboost, sparklyr, one-hot-encoding

I have many columns in my sparklyr dataframe(about 70) some of which need to be one hot encoded before I build an xgboost model using sparklyr's xgboost_classifier function. However I dont know what one_hot function to use and why ?

I know how the ft_string_indexer works and I have used that in combination with the one_hot_encoder function but I get a column that doesnt make much sense back.

This is the column returned. Does the xgboost_classifier work with this?

```
     1 <dbl [5]>   
     2 <dbl [5]>   
     3 <dbl [5]>   
     4 <dbl [5]>   
     5 <dbl [5]>   
     6 <dbl [5]>   
     7 <dbl [5]>
```

Comment: Xgboost requires a vector of doubles (all ur features)and a double (dependent variable ) as input this can be achieved using the feature hasher in spark ‘https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/FeatureHasher.html’